# Since we observe stars, galaxies, etc in their past - is it correct to say that our present is only present for us but is in the past from afar?

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, time, causality

So - I know that when we observe galaxies, we are observing their past. And that if the same past-them were to be looking at us, they would see our past. But when we look at their past - that is a moment in time that would, to them, be the present. So, what I cannot find an answer to (possibly because I don't know how best to search for it) is: does it then make sense to say that it is possible that a galaxy that is future to us, could be observing our present - but as past to them?

(if that is so then that opens up a whole can of worms that all time is occurring at all times, yes?)

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing complicated about this. Light just takes time to travel. Say you're on the Earth and observe the Sun. You see the Sun as it was 8.3 minutes ago. Similarly an observer on the Sun sees the Earth as it was 8.3 minutes ago. You observe the Sun was it was in the past, and they observe the Earth as it was in the past.

Does that mean that a future observer on the Sun would observe the Earth as it is in our present? Yes (that observer would be the observer 8.3 minutes into the future).

Does that mean all time is occurring at all times? No. The future hasn't happened yet, and the past has already happened (even if you can currently see what's in the past - but you could also do that by e.g. taking out an old photo album).

Comment: thanks for answering! I suppose I'm just getting in my head about how to rectify the knowledge that I'm looking at the present of an 8.3 minute year old sun, so that 8.3 minute year old sun now has someone from it's future observing it - rectifying that with acknowledging that the future has not happened. Like, I swear I understand that if *now* earth and *now* sun look at each other, they will both see the 8.3 minute past version. But that seems slightly different than what I'm stuck on.

Comment: I think you are confusing yourself. Suppose that the speed of light is a metre per second, and I am about ten metres away walking across your field of view. Owing to the time it takes for the light to reach you, you will see me where I was ten seconds earlier. The key word there is 'was'- by the time the light reaches you, I am no longer there but have moved ten seconds into my future.